# Image Magick: convert and composite in one command

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, alpha, composite, channel

I am currently working on a automation script to convert imgaes for use on websites. Every image gets a white and black border and is combined with a prepared alpha channel image. The black border (outer border) combined with the alpha channel will look like a shadow when everything is done.

I've got the following files:

- test.jpg (the test image)
- test.tga (the alpha channel)

And I convert the input image in 2 steps:
`convert test.jpg -bordercolor #FFFFFF -border 15 -bordercolor #000000 -border 30 test.png`
(adds the white and black border to the image and saves as 'test.png')
`composite -compose CopyOpacity test.tga test.png test2.png`
(joins image file with alpha channel from test.tga and saves as test2.png)

So now my question is: Is there any way to invoke both steps as one command? I know that `convert` also supports the `-compose` options, if I got that right from the manual, but I could not get it working. It would be best, if I could edit and join the image with the alpha channel with one command. (Command will be executed from my Application and I don't want to execute many sub-processes)

Maybe someone knows a solution for this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a solution right after posting this question...
It works, just using: `[...] -compose CopyOpacity test.tga -composite [...]` - just in case someone else needs this.

Comment: Can you post this in an answer as a complete example, and accept it as the correct answer? May be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: If you do write up the complete answer (as Bernhard said), you even can get 'upvotes' for it and 'accept' it too. This is an initial increase for your reputation score :-)